# Auto-populated field based on status change

Tags: sharepoint-server, auto-populate

I have a form collecting a lot of data, but I want to add a "Completion Date" field that will auto populate with the date when the Status field is changed to "Completed".

New to SharePoint, so please be detailed in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated column, [Completion Date], formula:

```
=IF(Status="Completed",TODAY(),"")

OR

=IF(Status="Completed",NOW(),"")
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:  The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

Can I use this calculation on a date field?

Comment: Maybe you're doing something differently. Create a column [Completion Date] of type "Calculated (calculation based on other columns)" and it will ask you to provide the formula. You then paste the formula there. On the same screen, you can see "The data type return from this formula is:", select "Date and Time"

Comment: I created the a column entitled Completion Date, but I don't have Calculated as a type, only the following:  
The type of information in this column is:  
 
 Single line of text
 Multiple lines of text
 Choice (menu to choose from)
 Date and Time
I selected Date and Time, but then under Default Value, entered the formula in the Calculated Value field, still receiving the error I sent previously.

Comment: When you edit a column, you can't change the type. You can delete the one you've already created and then create a new one. While creating a new column, you will see the "Calculated.. " option as column type

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked out now. Let me know if you still see any issues.

Comment: One more question.  If I wanted to pop open a calendar window to enter the completion date, when I change the status, can I do that?  Versus, having it auto-populate today's date.

Comment: Then you don't need a "Calculated.." column, which are auto filled with a formula. If users will select/type in a completion date on the data entry form then you would need a regular date/time column. In that case, you can set a default date, such as today, so that when a new item is created it would default to that date. But user can change that later. Please mark the question as answered if you think it answered your questions.